# One line for loop to multiple lines python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I've got trouble reverting below one line loop to multiple lines loop. here is the original code:

```
sequences = [[[item.strip() for item in itemset.split(",")] for itemset in sequence] for sequence in sequences]
```

Multiple line loop that I tried:

```
for sequence in sequences:
 for itemset in sequence:
    for item in itemset.split(","):
       sequences.append(item.strip())
```

It does not work as the original one. Any idea?

Comment: How about some sample data for testing purposes?

Comment: Also, review PEP8 for your indentation there.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: you should not reuse `sequences`, create another empty list and append to it every loop

Answer (score 3):

Your original question reassigns the result with the same name of the data (`sequences`).  Here, I assign the result to the variable `result`.

Given that you did not provide sample data, I just made some up (`sequences`).

Your original list comprehension is nested (note the brackets), with each layer creating a separate list.

`[[[x.strip() for x in something] for something in something_else] for something_else in sequences]`.

I've recreated that structure by creating a new list with each `for-loop`, appending as it goes along to match the original list comprehension.

```
# Sample data.
sequences = [['the, quick, brown fox'], ['jumped, over, the lazy dog']]

# Solution.
result = []
for sequence in sequences:
    inner_list = list()
    result.append(inner_list)
    for itemset in sequence:
        inner_list_2 = list()
        inner_list.append(inner_list_2)
        for item in itemset.split(","):
            inner_list_2.append(item.strip())
>>> result
[[['the', 'quick', 'brown fox']], [['jumped', 'over', 'the lazy dog']]]

# Original list comprehension.
>>> [[[item.strip() for item in itemset.split(",")] 
      for itemset in sequence] 
     for sequence in sequences]
[[['the', 'quick', 'brown fox']], [['jumped', 'over', 'the lazy dog']]]
```

Comment: Not quite the same result as running the original on those sequences: `[[['the', 'quick', 'brown fox']], [['jumped', 'over', 'the lazy dog']]]` You need another array.

Comment: Agreed.  I've amended the original to include it.

Comment: where do we need to add another array?

Comment: My original reply returned `[['the', 'quick', 'brown fox'], ['jumped', 'over', 'the lazy dog']]`, which was missing one level of nesting and therefore did not match the answer you get from the list comprehension you provided.